# Is there any anti-virus that only uses behaviour-based malware detection?

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus, antimalware

I would like to know any antivirus software that uses strictly only a behaviour-based malware detection technique as the aim of my research is to compare behavioural-based and signature-based malware detection techniques.

Comment: Do not repost closed questions

Comment: It's different. It's about behaviour based now and the article you shared with me didn't specify it.

Comment: It's the same reason why the other was closed ....

Comment: I mean I need help. You cant find it with a google search.